# UWP App size with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, uwp

I am trying to create a UWP app with dbStorage feature.

I looked at the UWP-Howto : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/index, and see that there are two ways of doing this.

1. Either using the basic sqlite3 APIs (I dont wish to use any 3rd party wrapper libraries)
2. Integrating Entity Framework with the App.

The latter option does seem to be a better option, since it is a ORM, but I am curious to know, adding it does it shoot up the App size in comparison to using the plain sqlite extension? Has anyone using it faced such problems?

Answer (score 1):

App size should be one of the last things to worry about when creating UWP apps. This size is a one time 'problem' when the user installs the app since it takes some time to download. There are a lot of improvements built into the Windows 10 Store to tackle this problem:

- Incremental updates (only update part of your app that changed)
- File single instancing (if the file/library is on your system, it isn't downloaded again)
- Partial resource downloads (only the language and scaled assets that fit for the device)

More info, see e.g. this [Build session](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-695).

If you want exact numbers, I would suggest building a small PoC with and without and compare in size (although size will change a tiny bit as well because you write different code pieces to make it work).

But the added size because of using EF Core won't be in the magnitude of 100s of MBs. The packages itself are [EFCore.Sqlite 71kb](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite/), [EFCore.Relational 475kb](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/), [EFCore 783kb](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/) and these even include multiple dlls, xml, ... so it's only a fraction of that. Together with a few more base packages (Caching, Logging, ...) and maybe a few extra .NET standard libraries that will be used that might not be used when using the basic API you'll have a few MB extra. In my opinion ignorable.

---

The things you SHOULD worry instead of the initial download time about are:

- Application startup time.
- Overall application performance.
- Performance of the developer (and thus the cost of creating the app).

If you're choice is between the native sqlite3 APIs and EF Core, it would be an easy pick for me (thinking on point 3 mentioned above). Just bear in mind that there are still [issues](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6253) with EF Core and .NET Native (the optimizations done by the store or when you build in Release mode with .NET native toolchain enabled). If you want to publish to the store very soon and have a rather large database, you might have some troubles to get it crash free. If you can sideload the app, just build without the .NET Native toolchain.

Comment: Exactly, I tried creating sample apps for comparing the sizes but the result cannot be relied upon, since EF seemed to add numerous libraries at the startup.
The other thing is as per the msdn link, we can use SQLite SDK in our UWP project directly by adding a reference to 
#include <winsqlite/winsqlite3.h> in our project, but I am not able to find any way to include .h in UWP. Any idea if we can actually directly use it or we would first have to create a wrapper library with this SQLite

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases

Comment: That's what I mentioned, it adds several dependencies from .NET Standard, but the total size doesn't go into several GB and in the end you shouldn't care about the size difference (and that is what this question is about) because of the optimizations.
For the 2nd part of your comment, you should ask a separate question. SO is not meant as a chat board, each (sub)question should have it's own link for search through Google etc.